# Hibernate java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm very new to hibernate, 
and i'm simply trying to make my first program that use it.

I'm using maven for building the project. I declared these dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5.SP1</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5.SP1</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.GA</version>
   </dependency>
```

Then i created the hibernate configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">******</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/vcsdb</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">vcsuser</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <mapping class="org.test.database.Project"/>
 </session-factory
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Then i created a reverse enginering file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Using eclipse hibernate plugin, i created the entity that represent the only table present in the database:

```
package org.test.database;

// Generated Jul 28, 2012 4:34:03 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * Project generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "project", catalog = "versioncontroldb")
public class Project implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String longName;
    private String siteUrl;
    private String projectUrl;
    private Date registered;
    private String description;
    private String userId;

    public Project() {
    }

    public Project(String name, String projectUrl, Date registered) {
        this.name = name;
        this.projectUrl = projectUrl;
        this.registered = registered;
    }

    public Project(String name, String longName, String siteUrl,
            String projectUrl, Date registered, String description,
            String userId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.longName = longName;
        this.siteUrl = siteUrl;
        this.projectUrl = projectUrl;
        this.registered = registered;
        this.description = description;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "long_name", length = 65535)
    public String getLongName() {
        return this.longName;
    }

    public void setLongName(String longName) {
        this.longName = longName;
    }

    @Column(name = "site_url", length = 150)
    public String getSiteUrl() {
        return this.siteUrl;
    }

    public void setSiteUrl(String siteUrl) {
        this.siteUrl = siteUrl;
    }

    @Column(name = "project_url", nullable = false, length = 200)
    public String getProjectUrl() {
        return this.projectUrl;
    }

    public void setProjectUrl(String projectUrl) {
        this.projectUrl = projectUrl;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "registered", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public Date getRegistered() {
        return this.registered;
    }

    public void setRegistered(Date registered) {
        this.registered = registered;
    }

    @Column(name = "description", length = 65535)
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Column(name = "user_id", length = 25)
    public String getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

}
```

And finally i added into main servlet classs for the application the follwing line of code:

```
Configuration sessionFactory = (Configuration) new Configuration()
    .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
    .buildSessionFactory();
```

But when i try to launch the application i receive the following error message:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:839)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

and:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2901)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1170)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:326)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:265)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:269)
org.versioncontrolanalyzer.controllers.MainController.helloWorld(MainController.java:18)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i found a solution myself.

There was several errors. Firs in the pom i removed this dependency:

```
   <dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
<version>3.2.4.GA</version>
```

Then i received another error: Cannot find hibernate.cfg.xml, i looked around and i found that this configuration file must be placed into root folder of java sources (so it will places onto classes folder when the application is deployed).

Finally i had another . of casting into declaration of sessionFactory, i declared it   as Configuration variable, but it must be a SessionFactory Variable.

Finally there is another problem with the mapping (wrong package for the Project class).

And it seems to works :)

Comment: If you follow [Maven Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) it's better to place your `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `src/main/resources` instead of `src/main/java`