# Tomcat 7, Hibernate 3.6, PostgreSQL 9.2 | Maven java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, maven, tomcat, pom.xml

I am working on a bigger project, that needs to get maven'd. So far I have successfully tested the project by including all the required .jar files in the WEB-INF/lib.

Libraries before maven:

- hibernate3.jar (Hibernate 3.6.Final)
- log4j.jar (1.2.8)
- postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar (PostgreSQL 9.2 JDBC4)
- commons-codec1.8.jar (Apache Commons Codec 1.8)
- commons-fileupload1-3.jar (Apache Commons Fileupload 1.3)
- Commons-lang3-3-1 (Apache Commons Lang3 3.1)
- cos.jar (O'Reilly 05Nov2005)

After /Configure/Convert To Maven I added all the dependencys:

```
<dependencies>      
        <!-- hibernate framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
               
        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
            
        <!-- PostgreSQL-JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1002-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- upload - O'reilly COS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>servlets.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>cos</artifactId>
            <version>05Nov2002</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- Apache Commons -->   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

to the project, but somehow always get an **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class business.HibernateUtil
    business.HibernateEngine.searchBatch(HibernateEngine.java:168)
    business.HibernateEngine.searchBatch(HibernateEngine.java:163)
    business.PersonAdmin.searchUser(PersonAdmin.java:222)
    ui.login2.doGet(login2.java:161)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
```

Both classes within the package business (HibernateUtil and HibernateEngine) set up the session used in the programme. Here it crashes in HibernateEngine (Line 167-169):

```
protected List searchBatch(String hqlQuery, boolean close) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
```

I tried different versions of all libraries but still didn't make any progress. I found out that the **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** is often caused by multiple imported identical libraries. Could it be that it has something to do with the hibernate-core import? I checked its maven repository, but somehow i dont find any double libraries.

Here my .classpath:

[image: a class path]

I am really desperate and hope someone might have an idea!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post: [Hibernate java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804194/hibernate-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hibernate-util-dtdentityresolver)

They removed 'hibernate-tools' and added 'hibernate-core'.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I have added hibernate-core but still recieve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class business.HibernateUtil. As far as i know hibernate-entitymanager usually includes hibernate-core.

Comment: Are you running your project over tomcat on eclipse?

Comment: no, i have installed tomcat seperately. I think it might be a configuration problem caused by hibernate. I'll check its settings.